# How to align text along an axis?

Tags: css

I want to have my left column aligned right, and my right column aligned left, so that they line up along a central axis, like this:

```
 16 January 2013 | Here is a line of text. 
26 December 2013 | Another line of text here. 
      4 May 2011 | Here is something else.
```

The HTML is in `<span>`s, like this:

```
<div class="line"> 
    <span class="date">16 January 2013</span> <span class="text">Here is a line of text.</span>
</div>
```

I've been trying to do this with `.line { display: table-row; }` and `.line span { display: table-cell; }` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is that ok if your line has a fixed width? :D

Comment: I guess so. I guess that's what's missing here.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<div class="line"> 
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;text-align:right;" class="date">16 January 2013</div>     
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;text-align:left;" class="text">Here is a line of text.</div>
</div>
```

div-s ok for you? :D

Answer (score 0):

I would stay with span:

**CSS:**

```
    #container
{
    display: table;
}

.left
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

.right
{
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container'>
    <span class='left'>Lorem</span> <span class='right'>Ipsum</span><br/>
    <span class='left'>dolor sit</span> <span class='right'>amet</span>
</div>
```

See here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/AyhyZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-cell value of display property.

see the example http://jsbin.com/eYOWaYA/1/edit